# Authenticate client certificate using HttpSelfHostServer in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting, asp.net-authentication

I have a service written in C# that currently works on Http. I want to migrate this to Https and want that when some client uses this service, there should be a option to select certificate to proceed and only certificates issued by one particular CA be allowed.

Below is the code for what I have done.

```
HttpSelfHostServer CreateServer(){

   var config = new MySelfHostConfiguration("https://localhost:1234/myService");
   IWebApiApplication application = new SelfHostedApplication(config);    //this is to do some logging and other configuration.
   HttpSelfHostServer selfHost = new HttpSelfHostServer((HttpSelfHostConfiguration)application.HttpConfiguration); //application.HttpConfiguration is same as config

   selfHost.OpenAsync.Wait();

   return selfHost;

}

public class MySelfHostConfiguration : HttpSelfHostConfiguration{

     public MySelfHostConfiguration(string address) : base(address){}
     public MySelfHostConfiguration(Uri address) : base(address){}

     protected override BindingParameterCollection OnConfigureBinding(HttpBinding httpBinding){
         httpBinding.Security.Mode = HttpBindingSecurityMode.Transport;
         httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
         return base.OnConfigureBinding(httpBinding);
     }
}
```

Below is Controller code

```
[Authorize]
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        //some code to do stuff
    }
}
```

What I have done till now is

1. Bind port 1234 to a certificate using netsh and thumbprint of the certificate.

With this I am able to browse to https://localhost:1234/myService (even though it is not secured for now since I have used a test certificate). But I also want that when I browse to the URL I should be asked to select certificate. I guess I am missing something in code where I need to ask for certificate and validate the CA. Can someone please suggest what is missing or what else needs to be done.

PS: I cannot change from HttpSelfHostServer to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `clientcertnegotiation=enable` with netsh.
i hope it works for you